# passing parameters in find of dynamic model

Tags: ember.js, model

I want to pass two (or more) arguments to this.store.find() ; I have app.router.js like

```
Router.map(function() 
{ 
      this.route('posts'); 
      this.route('post', { path: '/post/:post_id' }); 
});
```

and

dynamic route's model

```
model(params) 
{ 
    return this.store.findRecord('photo', params.photo_id); 
}
```

this will go to /photo/photo_id

now I tried to pass couple of arguments then it was giving error: no model is defined for some_photo_it (say id) I tried this:

```
model(params) {
    return this.store.findRecord('photo', params.photo_id,{param1:0, param2:25});
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And here is all I was needed.

[Query Parameters in Emberjs](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.2.0/routing/query-params/)

and thanks @Daniel also...

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can either find record by id, like you did:

```
this.store.findRecord('photo', params.photo_id);
```

Or you can find record by **query**ing your backend with some parameters:

```
this.store.findRecord('photo', {param1: 0, param2: 25});
```

You mixed both of these approaches which result in error you're getting.

Comment: ya absolutely n thanks for reply, But I want to pass params also to this dynamically changing id. Is there any way to do it. for example I have to get data from server by querying: 'API: root/v1/photos/{photo_id} ; parameters: param1=0&param2=25' . So the final request will be like: root/v1/photos/100123?param1=0&param2=25.